# AWS Glue Spark Job Extract Database Table Data in Parallel

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

Suppose I have this simple AWS Glue 4.0 PySpark job:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

tables = ['table1','table2','table3','table4','table5']

for table in tables:
    dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="sqlserver",
        connection_options={
            "useConnectionProperties": "true",
            "dbtable": table,
            "connectionName": "my-glue-jdbc-connection",
        }
    )
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=dyf,
        connection_type="s3",
        format="parquet",
        connection_options={"path": f"s3://my-s3-bucket/{table}", "partitionKeys": []},
        format_options={"compression": "gzip"}
    )
```

This job completes with the expected output in S3, however, everything within the `for` loop is run sequentially and as a result is pretty slow.

Is there a way to rearrange the code such that each `write_dynamic_frame` operation runs in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rearrange the code in such a way which allows me to pass the `table` name as an argument to the glue job then invoke a fresh instance of the glue job for each `table` so that the processing of each table can run independently from the others. You can use the boto client to invoke a Glue job or maybe create a simple lambda function to do the same.

Also to access the parameter you can use `getResolvedOptions`

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME", "TABLE"])
args['TABLE']
```

Comment: I considered this as an option, but was concerned with the overhead of starting a spark job on each table iteration. There would be 100s of tables to process.

Comment: I think the overhead should not matter that much if you are really concerned about performance. In my current organization, we have a similar situation where I have to run a Glue job parallelly for different files, and I would say that it is a pretty effective process. You will pay only for what you use. For example, if one Glue job takes 100 minutes to run and 10 glue jobs each take 10 minutes to run it will still incur the same cost but you will gain performance improvements.

Comment: While testing your solution I'm finding the jobs are still running sequentially. I've executed 5 instances of my job each with the table arguments passed in.  They are all in "Running" state. But only one job at a time is actually doing something. For example, Job1 reads/writes and only once it's "Completed" do I see movement on the Job2 instance, then Job3, etc... Any ideas what's causing that?

Comment: Probably your JDBC connection is limiting the glue job? Check whether the JDBC database connection supports concurrent reads.

Comment: Turns out each instance of the job was consuming all of the available workers, so concurrent jobs were stalled until workers were available. Thanks for your help.